# Unity - How come the AutoRotate() is smoother than ManualRotate()

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

The methods work but `ManualRotate()` is shaky and does not stay centered unlike `AutoRotate()` which is stable, no shake, and orbits around target. What am I doing wrong? I just want the same effect as AutoRotate but being able to move the turret with Mouse, that is all. This code is in `Update()`, here is the code. Thank you.

```
private void AutoRotate()
{
    if (allowedToTrackTarget)
    {
        Vector3 targetDirection = lastKnownPosition - transform.position;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        thisTurret.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(thisTurret.rotation, targetRotation, autoRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
private void ManualRotate()
{
    float xDif = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float yDif = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    if (allowedToTrackTarget && (Mathf.Abs(xDif) > 0.0f || Mathf.Abs(yDif) > 0.0f))
    {
        // Calculate adjusted speed based on distance
        float adjustedSpeed = AdjustedManualRotationSpeed(lastKnownPosition, baseManualRotationSpeed, maxManualRotationSpeed, 6.0f);

        xDif *= adjustedSpeed;
        yDif *= adjustedSpeed;

        // Update lastKnownPosition based on mouse movement
        lastKnownPosition += thisTurret.right * xDif + thisTurret.up * yDif;

        // Apply the rotation using interpolation
        Quaternion targetRotation = thisTurret.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(yDif, xDif, 0.0f);
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(thisTurret.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * adjustedSpeed);
        thisTurret.rotation = newRotation;

        // Reset z-axis rotation to 0
        thisTurret.eulerAngles = new Vector3(thisTurret.eulerAngles.x, thisTurret.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
    }
}
private float AdjustedManualRotationSpeed(Vector3 targetPosition, float baseSpeed, float maxSpeed, float distanceThreshold)
{
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(thisTurret.position, targetPosition);
    float adjustedSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(baseSpeed, maxSpeed, distance / distanceThreshold);
    return adjustedSpeed;
}
```